# QgsRunProcess does not show output

Tags: pyqgis

I am using QGis 2.18 on Windows 10. I want to execute an external executable file that is writen in python3 and show the output in the dialog provided by QgsRunProcess. The code I am using is:

```
from qgis.core import QgsRunProcess
my_cmdLine = r'"C:\Python36\Scripts\myExecutable.exe" -h'
my_process = QgsRunProcess.create(my_cmdLine, True)
```

I am not able to see any output, nor any error message. The executable works if executed on a cmd console, showing the help text of the executable in this case with the -h option.

How can I see the output that the program using QgsRunProcess or if it is the case see any possible error.

Moreover, once the output will be vissible, can I get it as is being generated by the executable?

Comment: Can you get anything to run from QgsRunProcess? That would narrow it down to a problem with your QGIS setup or your executable itself. Even a bogus command like `QgsRunProcess("", True)` for me brings up a new window with "Unable to run command" in it - are you seeing that? Is this from a running QGis or from a python script - if so please give a full minimal script with all your setup and initialisation.

Comment: @Spacedman QgsRunProcess.create("", True) just works as expected. It brings a new dialog with "unable to run command" in it. I am testing this from the python console of Qgis2.18

Comment: Moreover, I have created a one line python script called hw.py (not an executable as I need) with a print("hello world") and executed with QgsRunProcess.create(r"C:\Python36\python C:\hw.py", True). I can't see the text on the dialog as it appears on a cmd console. I only see **Starting C:\Python36\python C:\hw.py...** and **Done** inthe dialog.